# Generate report by storing schema in XML document

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-xml

I need to generate a report in `csv` format. Data is retrieved as `List<T>` and only certain columns needs to be displayed in the report. I am thinking of doing it by storing its schema in an XML document under App_Data folder and use LINQ to XML to retrieve the field names and create the report.

Sample XML:

```
<report>
<fields>
<field headercaption='Customer Name'>CName</field>
<field headercaption='Address'>CAddress</field>
...
</fields>
</report>
```

Is it advisable to completely depend on XML file this way or do I need to do it through coding.

**Edit**

Fields are properties of `List<T>` which needs to be populated in the CSV files. Header caption is the name of the column for the field in the report.

Sample Report

> Customer Name, Address,
>
> ALFKI        , 31 Independence Ave., Washington

Comment: Is it some sort of a custom report that can change at any time?  Because if not, XML may just add to the complexity without much else gained.

Comment: Right now format is fixed but yes, I thought by using XML columns can be easily added/removed. I was able to query them using Linq. But since I am doing this way for first time, I wanted to get feedback. Could you please tell what the implications in future would be by using XML.

Comment: If you want to be able to arbitrarily add/remove columns it would be even easier to use a plain text file, something like `CName|Customer Name`.  Read all lines, split by `|` (or whatever character you choose) and go from there.  XML might become useful if you were planning to put several reports into one file, and maybe give them names; or provide some way for other people to submit their own reports, etc.

Comment: Can you show an example of what the output should be? Do you need to show the columns headers or just the values?

Comment: @R0MANARMY, It makes sense and code is now better compared to XML. Thanks for your help. Please post it as answer, I will mark it.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, does your CSV file need to conform to [RFC 4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) or just have some fields separated by commas?  Because if you need to conform to actual CSV specification, then it would make sense to use a library for that. (That way I can add more related stuff to the answer).

Comment: I am now populating by just separating them with commas. I don't have any idea whether it should conform to standard. If implementation is already available with you, please post it as might be helpful for others.

Comment: I've gone through the standard, except special handling for double quotes, all seems normal. Right now, I am retrieving fields and their captions from text file and matching them with property names using reflection and populating in CSV file. It confirms to all other specifications like comma seperation, adding CLRF at end, etc.

Comment: So you're turning one text file into another text file?

Comment: I am sorry if it has confused you. I am just storing schema in text file i.e., the property names and their header just as you mentioned CName|Customer Name, where CName is property of type T in the passed List<T> and Customer Name is the header of this property in the CSV file. So, while generating the CSV, I am looping through properties defined in text file and retrieve it from List<T>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add/remove columns at run time in this one report, it would be even easier to use a plain text file.  Store column information in a format you can easily parse ( something like `CName|Customer Name`). When you need to generate CSV, read all lines, split by `|` (or whatever separator you choose) and go from there.  You will probably also want to add a comment or documentation note somewhere about the format *(in case you or someone else need to come back and modify it in a year or more).*

XML might become useful if you:

- plan to put several reports into one file, and maybe give them names
- provide some way for other people to submit their own reports
- create some authoring tool to allow people to customize reports
- localize column names in CSV.  You could define something like

.

```
<report>
<fields>
   <field name="CName">
      <header language="en-us">Customer Name</header>
      <header language="es-es">Nombre de cliente</header>
      ...
   </field>
   ...
</fields>
</report>
```

- want to experiment with XML libraries

In those cases XML may be useful because you could define an XSD and easily validate that submitted reports are valid.